# Set Window.DataContext to a declared property in the code-behind?

Tags: wpf, xaml, properties, datacontext, code-behind

I want to achieve something like the following (Notice the DataContext property of the Window element):

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    DataContext="{Binding MyDataContext}"/>

Class Window1 
    Public ReadOnly Property MyDataContext() As IEnumerable(Of String)
        Get
            Return New String() {"Item1", "Item2"}
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    DataContext="{Binding MyDataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I think it might be better to use a DependencyProperty, it should synchronize well.

Comment: I was struggling with the same problem. It worked now. Thanks for the tip.